# Spring PropertySource() How does it work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

in my resources/application.properties, I have:

```
classa.keypath=${user.home}/App/jsonfile.json
classa.attribute=TEST
```

in my ClassAConfig() class, I have

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="classa")
public class ClassAConfig{
    public static String keypath;
    public static String attribute;
    //getters
}
```

and in my ClassA(), I have:

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ClassAConfig.class)
@Component
@AutoConfigureAfter(ClassAConfig.class)
public class ClassA{
    @Autowired
    private ClassAConfig ClassAConfig;
    private static String keypath;
    private static String attribute;

    @Autowired
    public ClassA(ClassAConfig ClassAConfig){
        this.keypath=ClassAConfig.getKeypath();
        this.attribute=ClassAConfig.getAttribute();
        System.out.println(keypath);
        //prints out null
    }
}
```

Why is it printing null?

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="classa)` is missing the closing quote.  I assume this is a typo -- don't type code, copy/paste instead to avoid this type of error, which just makes it harder for us.

Comment: fixed. sorry about that. my original code is not on the same laptop and i cant copy paste because NDA